# Android, упростить использование объектов в главном и подключенном модулях

Tags: android, импорт, library

Подключил внешнюю библиотеку как модуль.

В основном модуле `app` есть некоторый объект.

Мне необходимо использовать экземпляр этого объекта в подключённом модуле. Но подключённый модуль об этом объекте ничего не знает. Просто добавить зависимость с этим объектом в `gradle` я не могу, потому что образуется круговая зависимость(о чём IDE предупреждает) и ошибки сыпятся градом.

Как разрешить эту проблему?

Реальный пример:

Объект в `app`:

```
public class FoodUnitDate {

    @SerializedName("date")
    private String dateString;

    @SerializedName("first_api")
    @Expose
    private float firstApi;

    @SerializedName("second_api")
    @Expose
    private float secondApi;
}
```

Который я не могу просто создать и передать в `lib`, `lib` о нём не знает. Я вынужден создавать такую же модель в `lib` и писать в основном модуле:

```
  com.applikeysolutions.cosmocalendar.model.FoodUnitDate foodUnitDate = new com.applikeysolutions.cosmocalendar.model.FoodUnitDate();
```

Затем наполнять его данными из своего `FoodUnitDate`(который в `app`) и передавать его в объект из `lib`, + при возвращении я должен буду распарсить его назад из внешней модели в свою.

Уверен что это максимально кривой подход, особенно учитывая что под такие вот костыли попадают громозкие объекты, параметры которых - другие объекты. Помогите избавиться от этого.

Comment: По идее должен быть какой-то core модуль, который описывает все модели, которые будут использоваться всеми или некоторыми модулями. Тогда app зависит от core, ваш someModule зависит от core, профит. Проблемы могут возникнуть когда модели начнут отличаться в разных модулях...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По совету Yura Ivanov начал использовать отдельный модуль для моделей. Это довольно просто и удобно, особенно когда проект раздувается.